# Error while opening shapefile in QGIS on Surface Pro

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error, windows, 64bit

I downloaded QGIS on Surface Pro, but when I try open a `.shp`-file the following
error comes up:

> Layer is not valid: The layer C:/Users/Izzyg/Documents/lab
> 1/__MACOSX/GEOG2480_F20_Lab01Data/countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map.

Reason: I have tried on another computer and I am able to open the file just fine on there. What can be a reason?

Comment: check (.shp, .shx and .dbf ) are in the same folder with the same file name. [Not sure why you have __MACOSX in your folder on a windows computer]

Comment: Some times having spaces in the path can screw things up (e.g folder 'lab 1'). I've mostly experienced this with geodatabases and ArcMap but worth a shot

Comment: You are not likely to have actual working files in a `__MACOSX` directory. Are you that is where/what your Shapefile is?